# Error with my JQuery code in IE but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer

I have this code below which works in firefox and all others except in IE. Am I making a syntaxt error somewhere? Can't seem to find it and its driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label:contains('Number')").html("Register:");
    $("input[type='textbox']").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
        /* create new visible input */
        var html = '<input type="checkbox" class="NetscapeFix" size="4" maxlength="5"  name="'+name+'" id="'+name+'"  value="1" dir="rtl" />';
        $(this).after(html).remove(); // add new, then remove original input
    });
});
```

Thank you,
Kaz

Comment: You might want to reformat your code!

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does any part of it work?

Answer (score 1):

One guess is that there's no such thing as `input[type="textbox"]`. Perhaps you might have meant to put either `input[type="text"]` or `textarea`?